# Is there some Java api to store complex JSONs to Cassandra?

Tags: java, json, cassandra, persist

Suppose you have some complex JSON like:

```
{A : valA, B : { C : [ arrayC... ] , D : valD } , etc... }
```

My question is, is there a Java API that persists such big objects in Cassandra?
After searching, MongoDB seems to perform this very well, but I want to know if it can be made in Cassandra via some API.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cassandra is adding support for JSON-like maps, lists, and sets in 1.2: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-3647